# trying to implement a js color picker that changes the background of a html5 document

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <script src="jscolor.js"></script>

    var Color: <input class="jscolor" value="ab2567">
    <script>
    colorObject.value=#Color;
    colorObject.value
    document.body.style.backgroundColor==(Color)
    </script>
```

here is the file jscolor.js, https://www.dropbox.com/s/qmvy2vzmin3z01h/jscolor.js?dl=0

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add event listener to do that.

See my snippet below:

```js
function changeColor() {
  var jsColor = document.getElementsByClassName('jscolor')[0];
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#' + jsColor.value;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://jscolor.com/release/latest/jscolor.js"></script>

<input class="jscolor" value="ab2567" onchange="changeColor()">
```

Comment: hi, i have tried implementing this, but it doesnt seem to work in my code, any idea why? and thanks for your time

Comment: have you tried my snippet by clicking on `Run code snippet`? My snippet was running smoothly.

Comment: yes, i tried it here, and it worked, but when implemented, the code would not let me pick color, it gave me the text box, but wouldnt open up a color picker

Comment: did you've load the jscolor library properly? And can you show me your complete javascript & html?

Comment: will do in a bit, dont have access to my files now, will at like 1pm

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3s9pgbdjdbjdoo8/assesment.html?dl=0 there is a drop box link to it

Comment: I'am on office, I've lot of restriction to opening internet pages... can you show it here?

Comment: ok, i will post it below, EDIT: i cant, there is too much text, it is bigger than allocated char size

Comment: fixed,  thanks for the help

Comment: Glad to help you... and, what is your problem? If my answer accepted, can you mark my answer & vote it up...

Comment: when i copied, i had cut of an < so syntax was broke aha and i have marked it as correct for you